# RethinkDB extract specific columns from documents

Tags: rethinkdb

How can I get some specific columns from the document below?

For example if I use the following query in data explorer I only get data for single key,  but i need to select multiple keys.

Example for retrieving a single key:

```
r.table('orders_1').get('2786c578-93e1-42d4-a7c4-6f3d7a3a2e00')('orderHeader')('customer_id')
```

I got `2` as result is 2, which is fine.

But i am not sure on how to select multiple keys and get their values.

Sample document :

```
orderHeader

{
"id":  "2786c578-93e1-42d4-a7c4-6f3d7a3a2e00" ,
"orderHeader": [
    {
    "created_on":  "03-12-2015" ,
    "customer_id":  "2" ,
    "entry_type":  "1" ,
    "ezp_order_id":  "ezp_1333234"
    }
]
```

}

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
r.table('orders_1').get('0334cfea-2277-43cb-b8eb-fa360105104a')('orderHeader')('customer_id')(entry_type)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `r.table('orders_1').get('0334cfea-2277-43cb-b8eb-fa360105104a')('orderHeader').pluck('customer_id', 'entry_type')` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is what i m except.

Answer (score 2):

If you want **the keys and the values**:

```
r.table('orders_1')
 .get('0334cfea-2277-43cb-b8eb-fa360105104a')('orderHeader')
 .pluck('customer_id', 'entry_type')
```

If you **only want the values**:

```
r.table('orders_1')
 .get('0334cfea-2277-43cb-b8eb-fa360105104a')('orderHeader')
 .pluck('customer_id', 'entry_type')
 .map(function(d){
   return d.values()
 })
```